# Showing DateTime .ToString() in debug VS 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datetime, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I am not sure if it is an update to visual studio or something our IT team has done to our machines/infrastructure, but while debugging visual studio 2022 I can no longer see DateTime's as a string (ToString() I would imagine).

For example:

[image: Debug screenshot]

Now I can figure it out, but it's just harder to look at than **"2024-01-01 00:00:00"**.

If anyone can help, I'd appreciate it, I have looked through the settings in VS that I thought would relevant, but I cannot see anything!

Comment: Which version? I can't see that "Non-Public members" field anymore.

Comment: It's rather strange that it has `Kind` at the top of the list of properties. How exactly was that value generated? If you just assign `DateTime.Now` to a variable, do you see the same behaviour?

Comment: Simple user error! You've (probably accidentally) pinned the Kind property on a DateTime property at some time in the past. See my answer for details.

Comment: @jmcilhinney What OP is seeing is perfectly explained by the pinned property. See my answer for details.

Comment: @phuzi, I probably should have noticed that but, in all my 20+ years of .NET development, I have never once pinned a property like that, so it's not something I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default value displayed in this view is indeed generated by `ToString()`:

[image: Screenshot showing default DateTime view]

However, it looks like you've pinned the `Kind` property so this is what you see instead.

[image: Screenshot showing with Kind pinned]

Incidentally, this is why that property is at the top of the list of properties too.

Unpin the Kind property and you will once again see what you expect.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I thought I was going insane! I have no recollection of pinning it, so I had not looked any deeper!

Answer (score 5):

Did a bit of googling and found this [github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/33287)
Have you enabled this?

Disabling this for me atleast gives the same result as you are seeing.
[image]

Comment: I'm not convinced that OP's issue is caused by the same bug!